How to Predict Event Occurrence Using Logistic Regression with (factor?) Variables
An event can occur[1] or not[0]. It depends on the age of the object! It can happen in summer, autumn, winter, or spring, and then it has a different probability depending on the season. It can take place in the forest, in the village, in a small town, in a big city, or in a metropolis. It then has different probabilities. It can happen on Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday, Saturday, or Sunday and has different probabilities.
There is a dataset that indicates whether the event occurred [1] or not [0]. This dataset indicates how old the object was at the time of measurement, what season it was, where it was, and when. Most combinations occur only once or not at all.
I determine the probabilities for the occurrence based on age + seasons. In this, the location and day of the week are not considered! I do the same for age + location and age + day of the week.
I now have the four probabilities for each measurement: age, age + actual season, age + actual location, age + actual day of the week.
Additional problem: It can be assumed that the event is much less likely to occur on Mondays than on other days of the week (at least in summer and in the forest), but there are not many measurements on Mondays. So, it is very unbalanced in this sense!!!
What are the possibilities (with logistic regression or other) to predict the real actually probability for each event (taken all information (day of the week, location, season, Age) into account)?
Something like this:
P(1) = Factor(Season) * Probability(Season) + Factor(Location) * Probability(Location) + Factor(DayOfWeek) * Probability(DayOfWeek)
Pythonic answers preferred.
Example Dataset could look like:
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# set size
num_rows = 100

# factors as int
seasons = np.random.randint(1, 5, num_rows)  # 4 verschiedene int Werte für Season
days_of_week = np.random.randint(1, 8, num_rows)  # 7 verschiedene int Werte für DayOfWeek
locations = np.random.randint(1, 6, num_rows)  # 5 verschiedene int Werte für Location

# DataFrame 1: actuall information
df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'Season': seasons,
    'DayOfWeek': days_of_week,
    'Location': locations
})

# DataFrame 2: probabilities corresponding to information in df1
probabilities = np.random.rand(num_rows, 3)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(probabilities, columns=['SeasonProb', 'DayOfWeekProb', 'LocationProb'])

# DataFrame 3: P(Age) and Event
p_alter = np.random.rand(num_rows)
events = np.random.randint(0, 2, num_rows)
df3 = pd.DataFrame({
    'P(Alter)': p_alter,
    'Event': events
})


Is there a single specific question here that needs to be answered?

How to calculate an overall probability from 'partial' probabilities

Determining overall probability from partial probabilities is not necessarily a programming problem, you might want to try a different stackexchange site for this question
